# How to ignore last trailing comma in application properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring app. In my application properties file I have the following:

```
list.of.company=METRO
```

and I have a bean defined in the xml file as such:

```
    <bean id="companyValidator" class="companyValidator">
    <constructor-arg name="listOfbanks" value="#{'${list.of.company:METRO}'.split(',', -1)}"/>
</bean>
```

And essentially what the companyValidator does is matches the companies in the application context and matches it to what was passed in the method inside that class.

E.g. if client calls companyValidator.match("METRO BANK"); then it'll return true as 'METRO' is included in the the string that was passed in as well as in the application properties.

What I've noticed is that we have to include a trailing comma after every entry for this to work. If I don't include the trailing comma on the one entry then it won't match. For the time being it'll be one entry as such:
list.of.company=METRO

and it'll soon change to list.of.company=METRO,TOMB

etc. But what I want to know is if it's possible for me not to include the trailing comma? I've experimented thus having the -1 in the split method.

Comment: It's absolutely okay to not include trailing comma for single value.